# Creating a nested hash from a sorted array in Ruby-- recursive group_by

Tags: ruby

I have an array of objects that has been sorted according to several properties of these objects.  In order of priority, these properties are `foo`, `bar` and `baz`.  This means that the objects are first sorted by `foo`; then subsequences having the same `foo` value are sorted by `bar`; and then those with the same `foo` and `bar` values are sorted by `baz`.

I would like to turn this into a nested hash that reflects this grouping.  Basically I'm looking for a recursive `Enumerable#group_by`.  The keys would be values of `foo`, `bar`, and `baz`; the values would be either sub-hashes or arrays of the objects.  Here is an example:

```
[obj1, obj2, ... objn].group_by_recursive(:foo, :bar, :baz)
#=> {
      foo_val_1 => {
        bar_val_1 => {
          baz_val_1 => [
            obj1,
            obj2,
            obj3
          ],
          baz_val_2 => [
            obj4,
            obj5
          ]
        },
        bar_val_2 => {
          baz_val_1 => [
            obj6,
            obj7
          ],
          baz_val_2 => [
            obj8
          ]
        },
      },
      foo_val_2 => {
        ...
      },
      ...
    }
```

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Came up with a pretty good solution.  Monkey-patch `Enumerable` like this:

```
module Enumerable

  def group_by_recursive(*props)
    groups = group_by(&props.first)
    if props.count == 1
      groups
    else
      groups.merge(groups) do |group, elements|
        elements.group_by_recursive(*props.drop(1))
      end
    end
  end

end
```

The properties you pass can be either `Procs` or `Symbols`

Comment: Since probably Ruby 2.4, you can use `hash.transform_values { .. }` instead of the merge trick.

Answer (score 1):

Similar to Sean's and lacking error handling ...

```
class Array
  def nested_group_by(*keys)
    return self if keys.length == 0
    groups = group_by(&keys.shift)
    Hash[groups.map { | k, v | [k, v.nested_group_by(*keys)] }]
  end
end
```